# AttributeError: 'WifiCall' object has no attribute 'master'

Tags: python

I need help im new in Python and Im Trying to Run this code but i have this error, thanks in advance.

line 32, in **init**
self.master.title("IT SUPPORT")
AttributeError: 'WifiCall' object has no attribute 'master'

```
class WifiCall():
    def __init__(self, master=none):
        self.master.title(ÏT SUPPORT")
        self.master.geometry("750x450")
        self.qrc = Canvas(self.master, bg='gray16', height=200, width=200)
        self.qrbg = PhotoImage(file=f"guestbg.png")
        self.bg_label = Label(self.master, image=self.qrbg)
        self.bg_Label.place(x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)
        
       # QR Code
        self.qr = PhotoImage(file=f"guestbar.png")
        self.qr_Label = Label(self.master, image=self.qr)
        self.qr_Label.place(x=121, y=97, width=226, height=294)
        
        self.qrc.pack()
        self.master.resizable(False, False)
 
    if__name__=='__main__':
      master = Tk()
      WifiCall(master)
      master.mainloop()
```

Comment: you haven't assigned self.master to anything. you need to put "self.master = master" before trying to manipulate it.

Comment: Sorry sir just start learning, can you explain it because i don't get it.

Comment: in __init__(self, master=None), youre assigning master to be none. But master and self.master is NOT the same. So you need to assign the value of master to self.master. Otherwise youre calling self.master.title when self.master doesnt exist.

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the variable `master` to the parameter given in the constructor, e.g `self.master = master`.

Comment: hi sir thanks, but which line i need to put it? when i try to put in below function and i run it the window open but its blank page